# Is there an alternative to textpos when using pgfpages?

Tags: beamer, textpos, pgfpages

I have a completed beamer presentation in which I make extensive use of `textpos` package for absolute positioning, in particular of the `textblock*` environment. Now, I wanted to add notes to this presentation with `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}`, which didn't work. I learned here that the `textpos` package and the `pgfpages` package interfere with each other and do not work properly together while using absolute positioning.

Is there an easy way to obtain the functionality of `textpos`, but in compliance with `pgfpages` (e.g. using some tikz commands) and preferably without having to reposition all of my `textblock*` environments? For reference, these environments contain single graphics as well as more complicated latex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on a solution to my problem. The code below is a rudimentary replacement for exactly the following environment

```
\begin{textblock*}{TEXTWIDTH}(XOFFSET,YOFFSET}
...
\end{textblock*}
```

provided by the `textpos` packages. It does not offer optional parameters, all listed parameters have to be set, and it does not respect any settings (like background color) of the original package. However, this code may serve as a basis for someone that needs a more general / slightly differnt replacement for the `textpos` functionality when using `pgfpage`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@textblockstar#1(#2,#3){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] \draw (current page.north west) ++ (#2,-#3) node [inner sep=0cm,anchor=north west,text width=#1]\bgroup\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
\expandafter\let\csname textblock*\endcsname\@textblockstar
\def\@endtextblockstar{\end{minipage}\egroup;\end{tikzpicture}}
\expandafter\let\csname endtextblock*\endcsname\@endtextblockstar
\makeatother
```

A short explanation of the code follows: The commands in line 1 and 6 allow @ to be used as a normal character in between. Line 2 defines the start of the environment and line 4 the end, while line 3 and 5 take care of the correct naming. The environment itself is a `tikz`environment in which a node is placed at the location defined by (#2,#3), the origin being the top-left corner. The node itself has a width of #1 and offers a `minipage` environment.

A nice feature of this `tikz`-based solution compared to using `textpos` is that blocks appearing later in the source code are printed above previous ones. This is true even for `includegraphics`commands.

Comment: Tk, It helped me with `tex2ht` to substitute textblock by minipage but keeping the same prototype (with parenthesis)